# Can't execute system/exec command

Tags: php

I am trying to exec/system an external script that should run independently of the script that called it. 
I am using xampp for windows at the moment as a development server, and I tried two methods, both don't seem to run the external script:

```
$run_cmd='c:\xampp\php\php.exe script.php';
exec($run_cmd);
```

Also tried using a new COM object:

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->Run($run_cmd, 0, false);
```

I put a log writing call in the script.php, but unless I call script.php from the command line, I don't get anything written to that log

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you make sure safe mode is disabled?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't execute syste](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469187/cant-execute-syste)

Comment: Did you try the full `\path\to\script.php`?

Comment: Is it possible that php.exe or script.php doesn't have execute permissions by your Apache user?

Comment: how can I tell if apache has no permissions ?

Comment: Solved. used full path for c:/xampp/php/php.exe c:/...../scripts/script.php Thanks you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check executable file permissions. Make sure the user that executes your php script has the permission to run it